# Can i use of am335x user uart without /dev/tty*?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, beagleboneblack

I am using BeagleboneBlack which has am335x processor and me curious to know about user uart working with /dev/tty node so my question is "Can I use user uart without using /dev/tty entry? or another node entry? or can I make a custom uart kernel module with a different node entry (not use dev/tty)?"

I know this is weird things but this question is for only knowledge

Comment: Yes, some drivers for serial attached devices use the "serial device bus" ("serdev") interface that first appeared in the 4.11 kernel, and don't go through the TTY layer at all.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will check it and inform you

Comment: Is serdev bypass Dev/tty layer ? So if I use serdev, how my serial debug is work ? Currently I use Dev/ttyo0 for debugg console.

Comment: To use the "serdev" interface, you need to write a kernel-mode driver for the serial connected device. For examples of drivers that use it, do a recursive grep for "module_serdev_device_driver" and for "serdev_device_driver_register" in the Linux kernel "drivers/" directory. There are several bluetooth controllers that work over a serial UART connection, for example.

Comment: For serial debug, you should probably use the TTY interface.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can. There are libraries that handle UART but just call the UART by another name, i.e. UART1, 2, 3, 4, 5 (etc).

I have found some libs that work like Adafruit_BBIO and pysabertooth. The pysabertooth lib works with the BBB and dimension engineering boards like the Sabertooth.

I mean literally, you can in a lib call the UART channels anything you wish. I see the answer the other fellow put down. I am currently not familiar w/ serdev. That may be an option but I am not skilled in uart/serdev in kernel 4.11.x.

Comment: Thank you for your support ,so are you saying that I can only change the name only(ex /dev/uart1) ? But UART node  would be in /dev directory

Comment: UART2: /dev/ttyS2, Rx: P9_22, Tx: P9_21. So, I think from what I understand, the UART needs to be called from /dev/ttySx and that is all.